# How to make a multiple API Calls iteratively and get the result when all are done in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I am having a requirement to make the below API's

```
<baseURL>/users/1
<baseURL>/users/2
<baseURL>/users/3
.
.
.
<baseURL>/users/10
```

Now I need to make the API call for the above URLs and when all are done I need to get the final successful response. There is no need that API call needs to go sequentially they can go parallelly also but the only is I need to get the final result of the last successful API sent, For that currently what I am doing is making use of Fork Join in the below way

```
    let user1= this.http.get(baseurl+'users/1');
    let user2= this.http.get(baseurl+'users/2');//In the similar way I have 10 values

    forkJoin([user1, user2]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our user1
      // results[1] is our user2
    });
```

Now when I am doing this, If the users/5 API call is breaking then all the succeeding API calls are not going.I don't want that breakage if any API call breaks in between. I am expecting something kind of Promise.allSettled functionality. I prefer doing using RXJS way

**I am using Angular 9**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the errors to ensure the source observables still complete so that `forkJoin` still emits:

```js
let user1 = this.http.get(baseurl + 'users/1').pipe(
  catchError(error => of({ error }))
);
let user2 = this.http.get(baseurl + 'users/2').pipe(
  catchError(error => of({ error }))
);

forkJoin([user1, user2]).subscribe(results => {
  // Handle results
});
```

You could then save the repetition:

```js
function getUser(id) {
  return this.http.get(baseurl + 'users/' + id).pipe(
    catchError(error => of({ error }))
  );
}

let user1 = getUser('1');
let user2 = getUser('2');

forkJoin([user1, user2]).subscribe(results => {
  // Handle results
});
```

You could even mimic `Promise.allSettled`:

```js
function getUser(id) {
  return this.http.get(baseurl + 'users/' + id).pipe(
    map(user => ({
      status: 'fulfilled',
      value: user
    })),
    catchError(error => of({
      status: 'rejected',
      reason: error
    }))
  );
}

let user1 = getUser('1');
let user2 = getUser('2');

forkJoin([user1, user2]).subscribe(results => {
  // Handle results
});
```